# How to reduce space between Chapter Name and Chapter Title in fncychap

Tags: spacing, chapters, fncychap

I am using the `\documentclass[12pt]{report}` with `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`. How can I reduce the space between the line which says "Chapter 1" and the title for that chapter, say "Introduction"?

Chapter 1

Introduction

I tried changing the values for the `\vspace*{}` command in the following, which are for the "Chapter" and the numbers like "1" in the chapter name, but this only changes the position of the top line of the box enclosing the chapter name "Chapter 1".

```
\ChNameVar{\fontsize{13}{-42}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\vspace*{-44\p@}}

\ChNumVar{\fontsize{46}{-43}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\vspace*{-45\p@}}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `\vspace{...}` before and after the chapter title  to your liking.

It has to be done for the numbered (`\DOTI`) and the unnumbered (`\DOTIS`)chapters

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{% numbered chapters
    \vspace*{-20pt} % adjust space before title <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
    \raggedright
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{25pt} % adjust space after title <<<<<<
}

\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% unnumberd chapters
    \raggedright
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-10pt} % adjust space after title <<<<<<
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1]
    
\chapter*{Method}   
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```